# Using wp_mail to send email?

Tags: plugin-development, email, wp-insert-post, wp-mail

I have certain instances where I want to send emails to both user and admin accordingly using `wp_mail`.
The first instance is when a new user is created.
The following code is used to create users:

```
//Get all users and if user exists get username and email or else create new user as support customer. 
$user = strstr($mail['header']->fromaddress, '<',true);
$email = $mail['header']->fromaddress;


for ($j=1; $j < $total; $j++) { 
    $mail = $emails-> get($j);

if(email_exists($email)){
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'username', $email, True);  
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'email', $user, True);
 }
    else{
         $userdata = array(
        'user_login'    => ucwords(strstr($mail['header']->fromaddress, '<',true)),
        'user_pass'     => '',
        'user_nicename' => ucwords(strstr($mail['header']->fromaddress, '<',true)),   
        'display_name'  => ucwords(strstr($mail['header']->fromaddress, '<',true)),
        'user_email'    => strstr($mail['header']->fromaddress, '<'),
        'role'          => 'support_customer',
    );
    $user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);

  if( $user_id ) :
        $get_userdata = get_userdata( $user_id );
        $get_user_email = $userdata['user_email'];

     wp_mail( $userdata['user_email'],'test sub', 'Email' .$userdata['user_email']. 'is created','');
    endif;
            if ( ! is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
                 wp_update_post( array(
                  'ID'          => $post_id,
                  'post_author' => $user_id,
    ) );
}
}
}
```

After the user is created both the admin and user should get an email.
I also created a template to be sent:

```
<section id="email-template">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="logo">
            <img src="./img/logo.png" alt="LOGO">
          </div>
          <div class="text-1">
            <p>Hi <b>Jeon Jungkook</b>,<br>
              A client you are in charge of just posted a new reply to his ticket <a href="#123">"Spring"</a>.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="message">
            <h2>Message:</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure non
              exercitationem maxime nostrum eaque eos quaerat libero explicabo id?
              Temporibus omnis qui dolorum provident debitis voluptatum veritatis
              ipsa necessitatibus mollitia quaerat consequuntur.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="ticket-button">
            <a href="https://codethemes.co/wp-admin/post.php?post=33177&action=edit" class="btn">View Ticket </a>
          </div>
          <div class="message">
            <p class="after">If you are responsible for the ticket, please go ahead and do the needful.</p>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <footer>
            <div class="down">
              <p class="up">Updates by FAQPress </p>
              <div class="vertical"></div>
              <p><a href="#">Unsubscribe.</a></p>
            </div>
          </footer>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Now I want to use this template and sent an email.
Similarly the second instance is for comments and so on.
If I can get help with this instance I think I can do rest by myself.

Comment: WP already has a checkbox in the settings to notify administrators by email when new users sign up. On a multisite it's int he settings page of the network admin under registration settings with the label `Registration notification`. Other than that, what exactly about `wp_mail` is unclear? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am trying to create a plugin that does this stuff so I don't want to use the WordPress default setting.

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't re-use the built in functions and APIs to avoid rebuilding half of it yourself. You didn't answer the question I asked at the end of my last comment though :(

Comment: Also, I want to use `wp_mail` to send emails to multiple users such as both admin and user at the same time. I have seen the functionality of `wp_mail` and also I am new to all this so I want to use it to send it to multiple users.

Comment: I'm unclear what the question is, you've stated your goals, but are you asking for examples of how to use `wp_mail`? Are you saying you know how to use `wp_mail` to send an email but want to know how to do a specific thing? You need to write a _specific_ question that can be factually and fully answered, but this isn't phrased as a question

Comment: if you're looking for general information on how to use `wp_mail` you should refer to the official documentation on wordpress.org at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/ which has basic examples

Comment: The question states that I want to send emails using `wp_mail` on certain instances like here after `wp_insert_query` but I don't how to do it.

Comment: @TomJNowell As, you can see I am trying to send emails to only the new users that are created. So, I can retrieve that email. Every time I use `wp_mail` It send emails to all the users.

Comment: I suspect that the reason the email is going to everyone is because you have them all in your `for()` loop, and that your `email_exists()` isn't firing the way you think it is.

You clearly outline that IF the user's email is found, that an email isn't sent, and you just update `add_post_meta()`. Then in your ELSE you send the email.  So what that tells us is that `if( email_exists( $email ) ) {` probably isn't returning `true`.  Debug that first.

Comment: In my else, I am creating the user and after that, there is another if that sends the email. I also suspected that it is because of the for loop but if I keep my `wp_mail` outside the for loop how is it possible to get the user_email.